# adding product listing on magento homepage with description

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-layout-xml

I need to show my new products on the home page as a list view. I have used a Magento widget, but it is not returning the description of the product. How can I fetch the whole details of the product in the home page as shown in the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out(template hint) the file from where your widget is rendering products. It's located in `app/design/frontend/<yourpackage>/<yourtheme>/template/catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml`/`new_list.phtml`

Go look in that file, you will see how and what values are the widgets printing. So if you want description within the foreach loop you can get by printing `$_product->getShortDescription()` or `$_product->getData('short_description')`

Similarly to get other stuff like in list page, please take reference from `template/catalog/product/list.phtml` see how the other details are being printed and get those here on widget phtml file.

Comment: But i couldn't find such a file. app/design/frontend/<yourpackage>/<yourtheme>/template/catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml/new_list.phtml

Comment: @hakkim which theme are you using ? follow theme fallback or find from where the widget section is rendering by enabling `template path hint`